# Centos 7 detecting only 3 GB of RAM

Tags: linux, memory, centos

Centos 7 is detecting only less than 3GB of RAM instead of 4

```
[root@compute ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2913        425       2488          8          1        228
-/+ buffers/cache:        195       2718
Swap:         3215          0       3215
```

How can I further troubleshoot , Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using onboard graphics? A portion of system RAM will be dedicated to the onboard GPU. You should be able to change this value in the BIOS (Default settings are highly recommended). Also, CentOS reserves a portion on RAM to be used in the event of a Kernel panic. This will not be usable.

Look into the BIOS setting and any kdump settings (or similar, I'm not sure that CentOS 7 uses kdump specifically but older versions did). This might shed some light on missing memory.

Comment: Thanks you got it right :)
I could find it in my Gigabyte motherboard under . Peripherals >> GFX configuration >> Change the setting to force and set the Integrated graphics memory value at uma frame buffer size settings

Comment: Glad to help!...

Answer (score 1):

Is it a 32bit computer or 32bit OS ? If yes, you cant see more than 4GB. Video memory will occupy space and make RAM invisible. So if you have a 1024mb RAM video card and 4GB of RAM, your computer will only see 3GB of RAM due to the 1GB of video card memory being occupied.

The only way to see more than 4GB is to enable PAE or have a 64bit processor and OS.

I would start checking that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions , RAM was used by the onboard graphic card